# Dealing with 128-bit numbers in MySQL

Tags: mysql

My table has a column which I know is a 128-bit unsigned number, stored in base-10 as a varchar e.g.

`"25495123833603613494099723681886"`

I know the bit-fields in this number, and I want to use the top 64 bits in `GROUP BY`.

In my example, the top 64-bits would be `1382093432409`

I have not found a way, but I have eliminated some leads:

- cannot convert to `NUMERIC`/`DECIMAL` because these are 64-bit too
- cannot use `LEFT()` because `1<<64` is not base-10 aligned
- `CONV(N,10,16)` would allow `LEFT()` but `CONV()` works at 64-bit precision only too :(

How can I get the `BIGINT` that is the top 64-bits of this number, so I can use that in the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: How about not storing them base-10, but base-16 instead – meaning hexadecimal values in varchar? Would be quite easy then to get the first 64 bits – would be the first four characters. (Assuming you store them all using a fixed length of 8 characters, zero-padded if necessary.)

Comment: @CBroe unfortunately the data is already in the table, I just want to report on it.  I cannot make schema changes nor change the code that generates the data in the first place.  Its a legacy system.

Comment: create a view with the new hex column? idk about the perfs then..

Comment: @Sebas But this again leads to the question how to do that...

Comment: right, `HEX()` also is limited en cuanto a its input... You could create your own HEX stored procedure that would split a string in n parts to process the parts independently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get at least part of the way there using floating-point math.

MySQL uses double-precision floating-point for non-integer math. This gives you about 50 bits of reliable precision for integral values - while this isn't quite 64, it's pretty close. You can use floating-point math to extract the top bits here using the expression:

```
FLOOR(n / POW(2,64))
```

where `n` is the name of the column.

This approach runs out of steam if more than 50 bits are needed, though, as even double-precision floats don't have enough significant bits to represent the whole thing, and trying to get any more using subtraction fails due to cancellation. (The extra bits are lost as soon as the string is converted to a number; they can't be brought back without doing something entirely different.)

Comment: (ah, I just typed a long string of decimal digits for my example; I'll add some more.  I'm not sure how I can get my string to be a float in the first place though?)

Comment: You don't have to. MySQL implicitly interprets it as a floating-point value when you use float operators on it - like dividing it by the result of `POW()`.

Comment: So what data-type does MySQL convert the string into *before* performing the division?

Comment: No, it's a 64-bit type - but the whole purpose of a floating-point number is that some of the bits (11 of them, in a 64-bit float) are dedicated to representing the scale of the number, so it can represent numbers far outside the bounds of a similarly sized integer.